# If $p>3$ a prime number then $\binom {p-1}{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} 4^{p-1} \pmod {p^3}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory

Here is one of Morley's theorem in number theory.

My idea is to begin in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ :

$\binom {p-1}{\frac{p-1}{2}} = \frac{(p-1)!}{(\frac{p-1}{2})!(\frac{p-1}{2})!}=\frac{(p-1)!}{(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(p-1)!}=\frac{1}{(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}\equiv (-1)^{-\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod p.$

Now, I want to build a solution for $p^2$ then for $p^3$ with maybe Hensel's lemma but I don't know if it's the right way or if it can work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Seems likely to be related to the theorem that for $p>3$, $$\binom{pa}{pb}\equiv \binom{a}{b}\pmod{p^3}.$$ The lemma's for that might be useful.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews We can use Lucas theorem and we have directly the theorem $(\mod p)$

Comment: The theorem mod $p$ is pretty easy, though.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews and for $(\mod p^3)$ we use Hensel ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In the paper [Morley's other miracle](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.3678) the proof is given exactly as you suggested, using these lemma's.

Comment: Hensel's lemma doesn't let you extrapolate from $A\equiv B\pmod{p}$ to $A\equiv B\pmod{p^3}$. It let's you (given certain conditions) *solve* $A(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p^3}$ if you have a solution to $A(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p^3}$. That makes it useless in this case. @Maman

Answer (score 3):

Just a partial answer, for now. By [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme's_theorem) we have $\binom{2p-1}{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p^3}$, and

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \binom{2p-1}{p-1} &=& \frac{\color{red}{(2p-1)\cdot (2p-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot(p+2)}}{\color{blue}{(p-2)\cdot(p-4)\cdot\ldots\cdot 1}}\cdot\binom{p-1}{\frac{p-1}{2}}\\ &=&(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\binom{p-1}{\frac{p-1}{2}}\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(1-\frac{2p}{2k-1}\right)\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*} $$
but $q(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(1-\frac{2z}{2k-1}\right)$ is a polynomial that fulfills $q(0)=1$ with roots at $z\in\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},\ldots,\frac{p-2}{2}\right\}$. By Viète's theorem, the coefficient of $z$ in $p(z)$ just depends on:
$$ \frac{2}{1}+\frac{2}{3}+\ldots+\frac{2}{p-2} = 2H_{p-1}-H_{\frac{p-1}{2}}\tag{2}$$
while the coefficient of $z^2$ just depends on:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(2H_{p-1}-H_{\frac{p-1}{2}}\right)^2-\left(4H_{p-1}^{(2)}-H_{\frac{p-1}{2}}^{(2)}\right)\right] \tag{3}$$
so Morley's theorem ultimately boils down to understanding the behaviour of $H_{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p^2}$ and $H_{\frac{p-1}{2}}^{(2)}\pmod{p}$, just like Wolstenholme's theorem is equivalent to $H_{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$ and $H_{p-1}^{(2)}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $(2)$ in $H_{\frac{p-1}{2}}^{(2)}\pmod{p}$ ?

Comment: @Maman: $$ H_n^{(2)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}, \qquad H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}.$$

Comment: Could you develop the part with Viète's theorem please ?

Answer (score 3):

In the literature, Morley's result has been published in Annals of Math 9, 1895. He showed the congruence using an explicit form of de Moivre's Theorem. For another proof see  the paper [Binomial coefficients modulo prime powers](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf) by Andrew Granville, section $9$ and the remarks on equation $(14)$. Here perhaps a better reference for the proof is Theorem $6$ in the paper [On the Residues of Binomial Coefficients and Their Products Modulo Prime Powers](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s101140100144) by Cai and Granville. 
A further proof is given in the arXiv-paper [Morley's other miracle](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.3678) by Aebi and Cairns, which is freely available.

Comment: I have to buy the second paper ?

Comment: Yes, buy it from me ! (I have access) :) But you are right, I added an arxiv reference. It gives all details and many more references (you will find more, if you search).

Comment: Nice found, but in the $\textbf{Lemma 2, a)}$ why is there an equality between $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{p} \frac{1}{i^2}= \sum \limits_{i=1}^{p} i^2$ ?

Comment: Because $x\neq 0$ runs through $\mathbb{F}_p$ if and only $\frac{1}{x}$ runs through $\mathbb{F}_p$; indeed $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is a group.